# Installing Ubuntu as Dual-Boot on SSD in AHCI Mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, ssd

Pre-installed Win 10. Downloaded the newest Ubuntu .ISO on CD. The installer does not find any SSD (Where also Win 10 is), only the HDD.

Checked the UEFI and it says my SSD is in AHCI mode.

Do I need to pic another distribution or is there a solution?

Comment: Try disabling the Fast Startup feature in Windows, shutdown. Then boot the live session again making sure it is booting in **UEFI mode**.

Comment: I got it installed, thank you. The problem was not that the SSD was in AHCI mode, but in RAID. So after changing it to AHCI, disabling Fast Startup and booting in UEFI mode I found the discs and got it installed. Now I got the problem that the GRUB doesn't show up, so I can't boot Linux, just Win 10. Maybe you could help me on that on my other thread...

Comment: It had to be one thing or another. I'm glad you installed it in the end. Now, just open UEFI settings and change Windows to Ubuntu in the boot order. This should make it boot to the Grub menu from which you will be able to boot Ubuntu or Windows (you can at anytime boot Windows directly by changing the UEFI settings).

Comment: Alright, I am in the UEFI now. Here I can choose the boot order between UEFI USB CD/DVD, UEFI USB Key, UEFI CD/DVD, UEFI Hard Disk: Windows Boot Manager, UEFI USB Hard Disk, UEFI USB Floppy and UEFI Network. Which should I boot first, or where to find the right one (in search)? Also, maybe it is worth noting that Win 10 is pre-installed on the RAID mode, whereas Ubuntu got installed on AHCI mode.

Comment: Your Windows must boot correctly with the AHCI setting in order to be detected. Grub won't do it for you as Grub can only boot working Windows. And having "Windows Boot Manager" is correct and expected (Windows installed in UEFI mode) but the absence of "Ubuntu" in the same list suggests Ubuntu was NOT installed in UEFI mode. Remember that how it boots is how it installs. For better results change it back to RAID, boot Windows, install AHCI drivers if needed, reboot, change back to AHCI and try booting Windows.

Comment: Only when Windows is happily booting in AHCI you should proceed with the Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Alright. Windows is booting correctly with both AHCI and RAID. I had AHCI enabled when I installed Ubuntu, because when I tried with RAID , the installation program couldn't find the NVM SSD... The Boot-Repair program told me to check if there is any nvme0n1p1 in boot order and to type in this in the CMD on Windows: bcdedit /set -bootmgr- path /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

Comment: So I can still not boot Ubuntu...